# R: How do I rotate x-axis labels in a ctreeobj from the party package

Tags: r, plot, decision-tree, axis-labels

I'm using the `party` package in `R` to create a decision tree with some data. My dependent variable has some long strings and so the horizontal presentation of the x-axis labels means that all levels of my dependent variable are not showing.

Using the `survey` data from the `MASS` package as a trivial example, with the `party` package loaded:

```
 data(survey)
 #remove missing value
 survey2 <- subset(survey, !is.na(Clap))
 TreeResults <- ctree(Clap ~ Sex + Exer + Smoke, data=survey2)
 plot(TreeResults)
```

The labels I wish to rotate are for `Clap`, and I would like these to print at 45 degrees for each node. My real data has two terminal nodes, just like this example.

I have looked at `node_barplot` and I cannot see an option within there to modify the orientation of the x-axis labels.

Could someone advise how to do the label reorientation?

Thanks in advance.

Update: printing the labels up the sides as per the suggestion produced this plot:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you want something like?

```
plot(TreeResults,tp_args = list(beside=F))
```

UPDATE OP indicated this was not appropriate.

Unfortunately I cant see an easy fix. You can redefine the `node_barplot()` function as follows:

```
altbp<-function (ctreeobj, col = "black", fill = NULL, beside = NULL, 
    ymax = NULL, ylines = NULL, widths = 1, gap = NULL, reverse = NULL, 
    id = TRUE,rot=45) 
{
    getMaxPred <- function(x) {
        mp <- max(x$prediction)
        mpl <- ifelse(x$terminal, 0, getMaxPred(x$left))
        mpr <- ifelse(x$terminal, 0, getMaxPred(x$right))
        return(max(c(mp, mpl, mpr)))
    }
    y <- response(ctreeobj)[[1]]
    if (is.factor(y) || class(y) == "was_ordered") {
        ylevels <- levels(y)
        if (is.null(beside)) 
            beside <- if (length(ylevels) < 3) 
                FALSE
            else TRUE
        if (is.null(ymax)) 
            ymax <- if (beside) 
                1.1
            else 1
        if (is.null(gap)) 
            gap <- if (beside) 
                0.1
            else 0
    }
    else {
        if (is.null(beside)) 
            beside <- FALSE
        if (is.null(ymax)) 
            ymax <- getMaxPred(ctreeobj@tree) * 1.1
        ylevels <- seq(along = ctreeobj@tree$prediction)
        if (length(ylevels) < 2) 
            ylevels <- ""
        if (is.null(gap)) 
            gap <- 1
    }
    if (is.null(reverse)) 
        reverse <- !beside
    if (is.null(fill)) 
        fill <- gray.colors(length(ylevels))
    if (is.null(ylines)) 
        ylines <- if (beside) 
            c(3, 2)
        else c(1.5, 2.5)
    rval <- function(node) {
        pred <- node$prediction
        if (reverse) {
            pred <- rev(pred)
            ylevels <- rev(ylevels)
        }
        np <- length(pred)
        nc <- if (beside) 
            np
        else 1
        fill <- rep(fill, length.out = np)
        widths <- rep(widths, length.out = nc)
        col <- rep(col, length.out = nc)
        ylines <- rep(ylines, length.out = 2)
        gap <- gap * sum(widths)
        yscale <- c(0, ymax)
        xscale <- c(0, sum(widths) + (nc + 1) * gap)
        top_vp <- viewport(layout = grid.layout(nrow = 2, ncol = 3, 
            widths = unit(c(ylines[1], 1, ylines[2]), c("lines", 
                "null", "lines")), heights = unit(c(1, 1), c("lines", 
                "null"))), width = unit(1, "npc"), height = unit(1, 
            "npc") - unit(2, "lines"), name = paste("node_barplot", 
            node$nodeID, sep = ""))
        pushViewport(top_vp)
        grid.rect(gp = gpar(fill = "white", col = 0))
        top <- viewport(layout.pos.col = 2, layout.pos.row = 1)
        pushViewport(top)
        mainlab <- paste(ifelse(id, paste("Node", node$nodeID, 
            "(n = "), "n = "), sum(node$weights), ifelse(id, 
            ")", ""), sep = "")
        grid.text(mainlab)
        popViewport()
        plot <- viewport(layout.pos.col = 2, layout.pos.row = 2, 
            xscale = xscale, yscale = yscale, name = paste("node_barplot", 
                node$nodeID, "plot", sep = ""))
        pushViewport(plot)
        if (beside) {
            xcenter <- cumsum(widths + gap) - widths/2
            for (i in 1:np) {
                grid.rect(x = xcenter[i], y = 0, height = pred[i], 
                  width = widths[i], just = c("center", "bottom"), 
                  default.units = "native", gp = gpar(col = col[i], 
                    fill = fill[i]))
            }
            if (length(xcenter) > 1) 
                grid.xaxis(at = xcenter, label = FALSE)
            grid.text(ylevels, x = xcenter, y = unit(-1, "lines"), 
                just = c("center", "top"), default.units = "native", 
                check.overlap = TRUE,rot=rot)
            grid.yaxis()
        }
        else {
            ycenter <- cumsum(pred) - pred
            for (i in 1:np) {
                grid.rect(x = xscale[2]/2, y = ycenter[i], height = min(pred[i], 
                  ymax - ycenter[i]), width = widths[1], just = c("center", 
                  "bottom"), default.units = "native", gp = gpar(col = col[i], 
                  fill = fill[i]))
            }
            if (np > 1) {
                grid.text(ylevels[1], x = unit(-1, "lines"), 
                  y = 0, just = c("left", "center"), rot = 90, 
                  default.units = "native", check.overlap = TRUE)
                grid.text(ylevels[np], x = unit(-1, "lines"), 
                  y = ymax, just = c("right", "center"), rot = 90, 
                  default.units = "native", check.overlap = TRUE)
            }
            if (np > 2) {
                grid.text(ylevels[-c(1, np)], x = unit(-1, "lines"), 
                  y = ycenter[-c(1, np)], just = "center", rot = 90, 
                  default.units = "native", check.overlap = TRUE)
            }
            grid.yaxis(main = FALSE)
        }
        grid.rect(gp = gpar(fill = "transparent"))
        upViewport(2)
    }
    return(rval)
}
```

all this did was add `rot=` to the `grid.text` call when `beside=T`
then call the following:

```
plot(TreeResults,terminal_panel=altbp(TreeResults,ylines=1.2, gap=0.05,rot=45))
```

[image]

SUMMARY:

you can hack the `node_barplot` function a painless way to do it would be as follows:

```
altbp<-node_barplot
body(altbp)[[8]][[3]][[3]][[23]][[3]][[5]]<-substitute(
grid.text(ylevels, x = xcenter, y = unit(-1, "lines"), just = c("center", 
    "top"), default.units = "native", check.overlap = TRUE,rot=45)
)
plot(TreeResults,terminal_panel=altbp(TreeResults))
```

and use the `altbp` which will rotate text by 45 degrees.

Comment: Hi there, my factor level names are too long for this suggestion to work. I have modified my question with the actual output from my data based on this suggestion. So far, the only solutions I can see that are quick are (1) reduce factor level string lengths and (2) reduce the number of factor levels from 6 to 5.

Comment: thanks for posting the fix, it's a lot of function programming. Within that code, is there any way to shrink the height of the terminal node graphs so that the factor levels have more space to be printed underneath? If it's in the code, if you point to where I can do that, I'm happy to play.